# ELB IP address change and long living connections

Tags: websocket, amazon-elb

I understand that IP addresses behind the ELB may change in time, new IP addresses can be added and removed depending on the traffic pattern we have at the moment.

My question is - how does this work with long living connections, e.g. websocket? Let's say I have persistent websocket connection to the web service behind the ELB. When AWS changes the ELB's IP address I'm currently connected to, replacing it with some other, what will happen? I cannot find a good answer in AWS docs.

Thanks,
Vovan

Comment: Don't take my word on it, but if I understand things correctly, ELB won't close your server (instance) and change IP's while you still have clients connected... of course, if it will, the connection will be cut and you will need to re-establish the connection.

Comment: That's my question. I heard somewhere ELB won't close IP while there are still active connections through this IP but I cannot find this behavior officially documented.

Comment: I doubt it's that simple.i.e., when downsizing, if you have a long term connection remaining as the last connection in a process and it's been open for hours... I would have written my LB so that it would disconnect existing connections under certain conditions, assuming best practices (and the Websocket protocol guidelines) regarding possible network disconnections have been followed and that the client will simply reconnect to the new setup.

Comment: My question is about ELB, not about custom load balancing implementation. I've found old amazon forum post https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=169865#169865 which states that after ELB IP address revoked, it still can be used by current connections for one hour. This post is five years old, I'm wondering whether something has changed since then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When AWS changes the ELB's IP address I'm currently connected to, replacing it with some other, what will happen? I cannot find a good answer in AWS docs.

In general there are two situations where the ELB's IP addresses will change:

1. Underlying ELB Failure

Think of the ELB as a scalable cluster of Load Balancers all addressable under a single DNS name, each with an IP address. If one node dies (e.g. due to an underlying hardware failure), the IP will be removed from the DNS record and replaced with a new node.

Clients connected to it at the time of failure will lose their connection and should handle a reconnect. It won't automatically be routed to a 'healthy' part of the ELB.

2. Traffic Variation

If the ELB is scaled up or down - because of modifications in traffic profile - as mentioned in the [forum post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=169865#169865) linked above, the connections will continue to function for some time, but there is no guarantee of that period (min or max). This is especially notable in cases where the LB is scaled up quickly to meet load ("cliff face" style), as the 'old' ELB nodes may be overwhelmed (or become so) and their ability to process traffic impaired.

Subsequently it does mean developers need to handle reconnections in both cases on the client side.